# vpc sc perimeter effect on looker studio blends

Tags: looker-studio, google-vpc

We are using bigquery as our data warehouse.Our data analysts are using looker studio as their data analytics tool.

we have applied vpc service perimeter to a project for all the services in GCP to restrict resource access to only certain IP network (office networks) so that users should not be able to open in the remote areas other than office premises.

When they connect the tables protected in service perimeter to looker studio they are getting less number of records compared to records count when tables are connected without VPC SC perimeter.Whereas when they run in Metabase with vpc sc perimeter applied to Bigquery api they are getting the records properly. What might be the reason for this discrepancy in looker studio.

I have tried some test cases from which I have not understood what is happening under the hood

case -1 : we have created table chart where only one table is connected which is of around 100MB.Data is getting loaded properly with and without vpc sc and we are getting all the records.

case -2: here table blended with same table.With vpc sc we are getting less number of records than without vpc sc(we are getting data properly upto 8MB)

case -3: here table blended with other table with vpc sc.Here also we are getting less number of records than without vpc sc(we are getting data properly upto 5MB)